# psql 9.5: gen_random_uuid() not working

Tags: postgresql-9.5, uuid, pgcrypto

`SELECT gen_random_uuid()`

produces output

```
ERROR:  function gen_random_uuid() does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I ran `CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;` on selected database and `SELECT gen_random_bytes(1)` works perfectly (`gen_random_bytes` doesn't work on other databases where `pgcrypto` extension was not manually created).

```
% psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.3
```

Ubuntu version is 16.04.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

you can check if the functions are defined using

```
select pg_get_functiondef(to_regproc('gen_random_bytes'));
select pg_get_functiondef(to_regproc('gen_random_uuid'));
```

or:

```
select * from pg_proc where proname like 'gen_random_%';
```

if both functions are not defined then you probably had an error with the extension creation - just drop it and recreate:

```
drop extension pgcrypto;
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
```

Comment: Function `to_regproc` doesn't exist either: `ERROR:  function to_regproc(unknown) does not exist`.

Comment: What version are you using? This was only recently added... Try the pg_proc query.

Comment: `cohenjo`, ok, I got it. `select version()` gave me `PostgreSQL 9.3.12 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu...` I upgraded Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04 but psql server wasn't upgraded properly, I think. `psql --version` really shows me `9.5.3`, that confused me a lot.

Comment: I installed 9.5 postgresql version but it didn't replace existing 9.3 version, it just started alongside but on the other port! So there were two versions installed and I had to move and upgrade existing databases from 9.3 to 9.5 with this tutorial https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Using_pg_upgrade_on_Ubuntu/Debian But even after this upgrade to make `gen_random_uuid()` work I had to manually recreate extension (`drop extension pgcrypto; CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;`) as you assumed. Thanks, @cohenjo!

Comment: I used `CREATE IF NOT EXISTS` and had this error. Consequent `DROP EXTENSION pgcrypto` and `CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto` helped. Thank you.